# Specific route with iterator on Standard Container

Tags: c++, iterator, std

I have a class with an standard container member, and I'm wondering is that possible that I make an own iterator with a specific route, for example it goes back and forth, and after that stops.

```
template<class T>
class compressed_string {
    vector<T> v;
public:
    typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator iterator;
    iterator begin() { return v.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return v.end(); }

    compressed_string& add(const T& elem) {
        v.push_back(elem);
        return *this;
    }
    basic_string<T> not_nice_way_to_make_real_string() {
        basic_string<T> tmp;
        for(iterator i = v.begin(); i < v.end(); ++i)
            tmp += *i;
        for(iterator i = --v.end(); i >= v.begin(); --i)
            tmp += *i;
        return tmp;
    }
};
```

main:

```
compressed_string<char> s;
s.add('q').add('w').add('e').add('w');

cout << s.not_nice_way_to_make_real_string(); // q w e w w e w q

cout << endl

for ( compressed_string<char>::iterator i = s.begin(); i < s.end(); ++i )
    cout << *i;
```

So with this iterator member the output would be the same in this two lines.

How is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Ok, exact question added.

Comment: Y U NO `reverse_iterator`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need an iterator that stores a bit of state:

- where it is (e.g. an iterator `v_it` over `v`)
- where it's going (e.g. `bool forward`)
- where it's bounded (e.g. iterators `v_begin = v.begin()` and `v_end = v.end()`)

and some otherwise invalid iterator to represent the end, such as `{v_end, backward}`).

Then implement the increment operator along the lines of:

```
if (forward) {
    if (++v_it == v_end) {
        forward = false;
        --v_it;
    }
} else {
    if (v_it-- == v_begin) {
        v_it = v_end;
    }
}
```

and similarly for decrement, if you want a bidirectional iterator; in which case, it would be polite to provide a `reverse_iterator` too. You should provide both pre- and post-increment forms.

You'll also need `==` and `!=` comparisons, comparing both `v_it` and `forward`, and dereference operators `*` and `->` that dereference `v_it`, and suitable `begin` and `end` functions; for bonus points, a `const_iterator` would be nice.

Note that you'll need random access if you really want the code in your question (`i < s.end()` rather than the more generic `i != s.end()`) to work; that's entirely possible, but rather excessive if you don't otherwise need it.

UPDATE: as noted in the comments, this particular implementation could probably be improved a bit; for example, it's possible to remove the need to store `v_begin` if you're a bit careful about how you define the end iterator.

Comment: I don't think he really needs to store the beginning of the range in the iterator, only the current position, direction, and turn-around point.

Comment: Yeah, if you can ensure callers compare to begin, you can remove the comparison in the second block.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Iterators are supposed to be able to go one step beyond the end of the range to compare with `end()`, and I can't think of a way to allow that without either storing `v.begin()`, or relying on undefined behaviour by allowing iteration to decrement as far as `v.begin()-1`. But feel free to add a suggestion to the answer, if you can think of a way to do that.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: the `std::reverse_iterator` works by storing the internal iterator to the one after where it theoretically points as a way to bypass the issue, all the OP has to do is take that into consideration when the iterator is in reverse mode.

Comment: Or, considering that you're dealing with a `vector`, use a `ptrdiff_t index` which can become -1.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Indeed, behaving like `reverse_iterator` when reversing (and handling that case when dereferencing) would work.

Comment: @MSalters: That's certainly an option if you don't mind restricting it to random-access sequences. Personally, I'd rather keep it as generic as possible, but that's just me.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I just noticed that the increment operator code in the question skips one at the turnaround point (assuming it behaves like reverse iterator when dereferencing), iterates to one-past-the-beginning(but then moves it to the turnaround for some reason)

Comment: @MooingDuck: So it does. Well, my answer provides a starting point for whatever iteration is actually needed. Someone else can provide a complete implementation if they feel like it.